# Битрикс: Создание заказа из xml через D7

Tags: php, xml, битрикс

добрый день.
Импортируя заказы через xml, столкнулся с проблемой: если добавляю товары - заказ создается, товары тоже попадают, но отваливаются отгрузки и оплаты.
Если закомментировать код добавления товара, то отгрузки с оплатами встают как надо.
﻿
﻿Чую проблема в задании свойств добавляемого товара, но не могу понять как надо сделать...

﻿﻿Подскажите, кто сталкивался, что я делаю не так?
﻿Заранее благодарен

Пользовался следующими статьями:
https://github.com/SidiGi/bitrix-info/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0...

https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-order-bitrix-d7

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=8409

вот код:

```
<?php 
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");


    use \Bitrix\Main,
        \Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc as Loc,
        Bitrix\Main\Loader,
        Bitrix\Main\Config\Option,
        Bitrix\Sale\Delivery,
        Bitrix\Sale\PaySystem,
        Bitrix\Sale,
        Bitrix\Sale\Order,
        Bitrix\Sale\DiscountCouponsManager,
        Bitrix\Main\Context;


    if (!Loader::IncludeModule('sale'))
        die();
    if (!Loader::IncludeModule('iblock'))
        die();



if ($_POST['pass']=='' && $_POST['login']=='shop_order') {  # задумать пароль

    ///fields
    $order_status = 0; ///выставляемый статус заказа. т.е. при 0 - у нас все ОК, 1- "Загружен с ошибками", что-то иное - по усмотрению

    $shippingId = 2;
    $paymentId = 1; # т.к. эти два параметра будут передаваться с shop.ru(константно причем), а, следовательно, отличаться от имеющихся тут, укажем их вручную: доставка курьером и оплата наликом ему же


    function getPropertyByCode($propertyCollection, $code)  {
        foreach ($propertyCollection as $property)
        {
            if($property->getField('CODE') == $code)
                return $property;
        }
    }

    $siteId = \Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getSite();

    /* пример входного xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><orders><order>
                        <order_code>e_29680</order_code>
                        <name>Евгений тестовыйЗаказ не_звоните</name>
                        <phone>+7 (000) 000-00-00</phone>
                        <email>my@mail.ru</email>
                        <address>Москва, ул. Пушкина, кв. Колотушкина</address>
                        <comment>Оплата наличными</comment>
                        <shipping_id>1</shipping_id>
                        <shipping_cost>0</shipping_cost>
                        <payment_id>1</payment_id>
                        <discount>0</discount>
                        <total_cost>1055</total_cost>
                        <order_time>1504152151</order_time>
                        <products>
                            <product>
                                <code>eap211957</code>
                                <name>product_name</name>
                                <amount>5.00</amount>
                                <price>211</price>
                                <barcode>1234567</barcode>
                            </product>

                            </products></order></orders>

    */

  $orderxml = new SimpleXMLElement($_POST['data']);

  $currencyCode = Option::get('sale', 'default_currency', 'RUB');

  DiscountCouponsManager::init();


    $basket = Bitrix\Sale\Basket::create($siteId);

    foreach ($orderxml->order->products->product as $product) {
        #есть у нас штрих $product['barcode'], по нему ищем предложение, на основе которого уже достаем продукт
        if ($product->barcode=='') {
      #send angry mail
        }else {
            $result=CIBlockElement::GetList([],["IBLOCK_ID"=>3,"PROPERTY_BARCODE"=>$product->barcode,false,false,['ID']  ]);
            if ($result->SelectedRowsCount()  ) {
                $offer = $result->fetch(); ///беру только первое попавшееся предложение

                $productArr = CCatalogSku::GetProductInfo($offer['ID']);
                if ($productArr) {
                    $productID = $productArr['ID'];
﻿
                    # Если создается товар, то не добавляются отгрузки и оплаты !!!!

﻿                   $item = $basket->createItem("catalog", $productID);
                    $item->setFields(array(
                                    'QUANTITY' => $product->amount,
                                    'CURRENCY' => $currencyCode,
                                    'LID' => $siteId,
                                    'NAME' => $product->name,
                                    'PRICE' => $product->price,
                                ));

                } else {
                    $order_status = 1;

                }

            } else {
                $order_status = 1;
            }
        }   
    }


   $order = Order::create($siteId, \CSaleUser::GetAnonymousUserID());                            

    $order->setPersonTypeId(1); # физ.лицо
    $order->setField('CURRENCY', $currencyCode);
        $order->setField('USER_DESCRIPTION', $orderxml->order[0]->comment); // Устанавливаем поля комментария покупателя


     $order->setBasket($basket);
     $order->save();




      #отгрузка
    $shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentCollection();
    $shipment = $shipmentCollection->createItem(
            Bitrix\Sale\Delivery\Services\Manager::getObjectById($shippingId)
        );
    $shipmentItemCollection = $shipment->getShipmentItemCollection();
    # вся корзина в одной отгрузке
    foreach ($basket as $basketItem)
        {
            $item = $shipmentItemCollection->createItem($basketItem);
            $item->setQuantity($basketItem->getQuantity());
        }


    # оплаты
    $paymentCollection = $order->getPaymentCollection();
    $payment = $paymentCollection->createItem(
            Bitrix\Sale\PaySystem\Manager::getObjectById($paymentId)
        );    

    $payment->setField("SUM", $order->getPrice());
    $payment->setField("CURRENCY", $order->getCurrency());


    # Устанавливаем свойства
    $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
    $phoneProp = $propertyCollection->getPhone();
    $phoneProp->setValue($orderxml->order[0]->phone);
    $nameProp = $propertyCollection->getPayerName();
    $nameProp->setValue($orderxml->order[0]->name);
    $emailProperty = getPropertyByCode($propertyCollection, 'EMAIL');
    $emailProperty->setValue($orderxml->order[0]->email);



    $order->doFinalAction(true);
    $result = $order->save();
    if (!$result->isSuccess()) {
            //$result->getErrors();
    }

        $orderId = $order->GetId();

        ob_start();
        var_dump($_POST);
        $result = ob_get_clean();

        ob_start();
        var_dump($_POST['data']);
        $result2 = ob_get_clean();



        ///return $result;
        $to     = '';
        $subject = 'intercept order';

        $headers = 'From: request@sender.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: request@sender.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $message = $result.' + orderId = '.$orderId;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

}
```

﻿В конце кода мне на почту засылается письмо с прилетевшей xml-кой и айдишником создавшегося заказа.
﻿Так вот, при добавлении товара это письмо тоже не прилетает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну у меня как обычно, нет бы доку внимательно почитать...
проблема была в

```
$item->setFields(array(  'QUANTITY' => $product->amount,
                                    'CURRENCY' => $currencyCode,
                                    'LID' => $siteId,
                                    'NAME' => $product->name,
                                    'PRICE' => $product->price,
                                ));
```

Например, $product->amount - Это SimpleXMLElement, а не значение.

Помогло простое приведение типа:

```
$fieldArray = array(            'QUANTITY' => (int) $product->amount,
                                    'CURRENCY' => $currencyCode,
                                    'LID' => $siteId,
                                    'NAME' => (string) $product->name,
                                    'PRICE' => (string) $product->price,
                                );
$item->setFields($fieldArray);
```